# Leer un documento csv

Tags: c#

Mi programa quiere leer un documento csv el cual contiene una conjunto de datos y necesito leerlos e ingresarlos a un datagridview para poder manipularlos en mi sistema

Comment: Hola. ¿Cuál es tu pregunta? ¿Con qué código estás intentando resolver el problema que describes? ¿Qué error encuentras al usarlo?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), tambien [¿has intentado algo?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874/), [¿Qué has investigado?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2878) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes ayudarte con tools como ser

[CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/)

agregas la referencia usando `nuget`

Analiza el ejemplo

[Get Class Records](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/reading/get-class-records/)

define una class

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

en donde cada separador del `csv` concide con una propiedad, para despues usar

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader("path\\to\\file.csv"))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
{
    var records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>();

    datagridView1.DataSource = records;
}
```

como obtienes una lista de la clase puede asignarla como origen de datos del grid